# Is it possible to create an object of class X in a member function of class X itself in python and operate on the object references

Tags: python, class, oop

hypothetical code in which objects are created inside the class member function itself and then their references are assigned to a global variable , next the original references are assigned some other value

```
object_list = []
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        ....
    def my_method():
        obj1 = X()
        obj2 = X()
        object_list = [obj1,obj2]
        obj1 = ''
        obj2 = ''
```

Comment: At least try to run it first.

Comment: Since `obj1` and `obj2` are names local to `my_method`, it doesn't matter what you do with them after putting the objects in `object_list`; they go out of scope when `my_method` returns.

Comment: i tried by there were some errors , totally unrelated to what i have asked , TypeError: get_num() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given , when infact i have provided no arguments in the method call

Comment: in the accepted answer , i have declared a global variable a='' , then  initalised the a = Animal('johndoe', 5) inside the class method , a.description() does execute outside the member function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? Creating an instance within the class itself? Well this code works just fine in python 3.4, though I am unaware of future consequences this might cause.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def description(self): 
        print (self.name)
        print (self.age)
    def testt(self):
        animo = Animal('johndoe', 5)
        animo.description()

horse = Animal('trevor', 4)
horse.testt()
```

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for , but can the object created inside the class' member function be accessed outside the class , i think no because it is a local member of the testt function , but if it's reference is assigned to a global variable , can then it be accessed outside the class

Comment: tested it , it does work when a global variable is assigned a reference , but what i am interested in knowing further is when the parent object is destroyed by the garbage collector will the child object also be destroyed ?

Comment: Objects in Python are neither global nor local, only the names that refer to them are. Likewise, the reference count does not distinguish between local and global references.

Comment: As long as you don't try to create an object of the same type in `__init__` (which would cause an infinite loop!) there's no reason you can't create objects of the same class. People do this all the time, e.g. `class vector: def __add__(self, other): return vector(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)`.